# Django - Why doesn't reverse work?

Tags: django, reverse

I'm trying to make a view redirect to another view so user's can't access it without a condition being met. In this case, a successful password change. I also want to achieve this using HttpResponseRedirect.

Now, I've never used reverse before, but I figured that this is the way to do that. Problem is that I can't get reverse to work. I get the following error:

ViewDoesNotExist at /account/password/
Could not import findadownload.main.views.foo. View does not exist in module findadownload.main.views.

```
# URLS

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings


#SANDY
from findadownload.sandy.views import *


#TRIVIARIA
from findadownload.trivia.views import *
from findadownload.accounts.views import *


# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'findadownload.main.views.presidium_home', name='presidium_home'),
    (r'^web/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web'),
    (r'^web/developers/$', sandy_developers),


    #SANDY (for findadownload!)
    (r'^get/sandy/$', get_sandy),
    (r'^get/sandy/download/$', get_sandy_download),
    (r'^sandy/register/$', sandy_registration),
    (r'^sandy/complete/$', sandy_complete),
    (r'^web/shared/$', sandy_shared_files),
    (r'^web/remove/all/$', sandy_remove_all),
    (r'^web/remove/(?P<file_id>\w+)/$', sandy_remove_file),
    (r'^about/$', 'findadownload.main.views.about'),
    (r'^pytech/$', 'findadownload.main.views.pytech'), 
    (r'^pytech/aboutus$', 'findadownload.main.views.pytech_about'),
    (r'^pytech/services$', 'findadownload.main.views.pytech_services'),
    (r'^pytech/support$', 'findadownload.main.views.pytech_support'),
    (r'^pytech/contactus$', 'findadownload.main.views.pytech_contact'),
    (r'^pytech/sitemap$', 'findadownload.main.views.pytech_sitemap'),
    (r'^pytech/search/$', 'findadownload.main.views.pytech_search'),
    (r'^presidium', 'findadownload.main.views.presidium_home'),


    #TRIVIARIA
    (r'^register/$', register),
    (r'^login/$', login_view, {'template': 'trivia/registration/login.html'}),
    (r'^logout/$', logout_view),
    (r'^trivia/$', submit_question, {'template': 'trivia/trivia_questions.html'}),
    (r'^challenges/$', submit_question, {'template': 'trivia/trivia_challenges.html'}),
    (r'^question/thanks/$', question_thanks),
    (r'^question/answer/$', submit_answer),
    (r'^question/answer/result/(\d+)/(.*)/$', answer_result),
    (r'^question/answer/challenge/$', challenge_answer),
    (r'^account/$', upload_avatar),
    (r'^account/password/$', password_change),
    url(r'^account/password/success/$', 'findadownload.accounts.views.password_success'),
    (r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', view_user_profile, {'template': 'trivia/trivia_view_user_questions.html'}),
    (r'^(?P<username>\w+)/trivia/$', view_user_profile, {'template': 'trivia/trivia_view_user_questions.html'}),
    (r'^(?P<username>\w+)/challenges/$', view_user_profile, {'template': 'trivia/trivia_view_user_challenges.html'}),




    #FILE SHARING
    (r'^web/share/(?P<file_id>\w+)/$', sandy_download),
    (r'^web/report/(?P<file_id>\w+)/$', sandy_file_report),
    (r'^web/like/(?P<file_id>\w+)/$', like_download),
    #OTHER
    (r'^web/profile/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_profile'),
    (r'^web/edit/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_edit'),
    (r'^trivia/$', 'findadownload.main.views.trivia_home', {'template': 'trivia/registration/index.html'}),
    (r'^web/get/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_get'),
    (r'^web/progress/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_progress'),
    (r'^web/foo/$', 'findadownload.main.views.foo'),
    (r'^web/search/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_search'),
    (r'^web/logout/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_logout'),
    (r'^web/resend/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_resend'),
    (r'^web/home/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_home'),
    (r'^web/history/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_history'),
    (r'^web/verify/(?P<link>\w+)/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_activate'),
    (r'^web/help/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_help'),
    (r'^web/welcome/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'findadownload.main.views.welcome'),
    (r'^web/terms/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_terms'),
    (r'^web/privacy/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_privacy'),
    (r'^web/signup/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_signup'),
    (r'^web/login/$', 'findadownload.main.views.web_login'),
    (r'^test$', 'findadownload.main.views.test'),
    # url(r'^findadownload/', include('findadownload.foo.urls')),


    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)


if 1:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^uploads/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
            'show_indexes': True,
        }),
   )




urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()



    # VIEWS

    from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
    from findadownload.accounts.forms import *
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.contrib import auth
    from findadownload.accounts.models import *
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from findadownload.trivia.models import *


    def password_success(request):
        return render_to_response('trivia/trivia_password_success.html')

    def password_change(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            # if for is submitted
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = PasswordForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
                # for the avatar part
                if form.is_valid():
                    cd = form.cleaned_data
                    request.user.set_password(cd['confirm_password'])
                    request.user.save()`enter code here`
                    # redirect to profile page after POST
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('findadownload.accounts.views.password_success'))
            else:
                form = PasswordForm(user=request.user)

            # render empty form
            return render_to_response('trivia/trivia_password_change.html', {'form': form},
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/?next=%s' % request.path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify `name` kwargs in you url, in this case :

```
url(r'^account/password/success/$', 'findadownload.accounts.views.password_success', name = 'password_success')
```

Then use reverse like this :

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('password_success'))
```

What you pass in `reverse` is the `name` kwarg on urlpatterns.

EDIT:

Can i see the rest of your `urls.py`. I think the problem is not on `reverse`, because Django can't find view named `foo`.

Comment: Alright, cool. I solved it! Well, you did. The problem is that my brother is working on apps using the same urls.py that I'm using and that foo view was conflicting with the reverse function in my view. So I simply commented it out and voila! It works now! I'm going to examine that view more thoroughly later to see what it has in it that's causing the problem, but for now I'll leave it commented out.   Anyway, I really appreciate your help. Thanks :)